# Programmatically turn module/set of functions into a Python class

Tags: python, class, function, methods, module

Suppose I have a file with a bunch methods as bunch_methods.py:

```
def one(x):
  return int(x)

def two(y)
  return str(y)
```

Is there a way to take that group of methods by importing the module whole or select methods, and turn the imported into a class?

e.g. pseudo-wise

```
def make_class_from_module(which_module_or_listing_of_methods):
    class = turn_module_to_class(which_module_or_listing_of_methods)
    return class
```

so

BunchClass = make_class_from_module(bunch_methods)

Sounds legit in my mind, but how viable is it? How would I begin to do something like this, if I should even, or what are my alternatives?

Why would I want to do this? Right now it is a mental & learning exercise, but my specific use in mind is take methods and create [flask-classy FlaskView classes](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Classy/). I'd like to potentially take a grab bag of methods and potentially use & reuse them in differing contexts with FlaskView

---

Comment: Why do you want this?  None of the functions have any state (as far as you've shown), so there really isn't any purpose for having a class here.

Comment: What are you planning to do with this class?

Comment: To add to what @mgilson said, a module is already an instance of a class of type `module`.  What would the value be of wrapping or mutating that container class of stateless functions with or into another container class?

Comment: I don't see how `flask-classy` is a reason to do that. I doubt that is implemented with something like this.

Comment: `bunch_methods.py` doesn't contain methods, just functions, so at best they could be turned into static methods of an instance of some class. They would already be contained in a module called `bunch_methods` if you `import`ed, them, so what advantage would be gained by making them part a class?

Comment: Why not? Suppose I don't know beforehand what FlaskViews I'm going to make, suppose I need to aggregate some common methods to dispatch to different flaskviews in different blueprints, etc. I can see some need to do things dynamically.

Comment: http://www.ianlewis.org/en/dynamically-adding-method-classes-or-class-instanc would seem to indicate that there is a way to add functions to classes.

Comment: Sure it can be done. Notice that the `new_method()` function added has a `self` parameter which it used to reference another attribute of the instance? It thus has the makings of a true method.

Comment: After thinking awhile why anyone would want to do this, it dawned on me that turning a module into a class allows class inheritance. The pattern may not be recommendable, but it certainly is an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also solve this problem using the `type` meta-class.  The format for using `type` to generate a class is as follows:

```
type(name of the class, 
   tuple of the parent class (for inheritance, can be empty), 
   dictionary containing attributes names and values)
```

First, we need to rework your functions to take a class as the first attribute.

```
def one(cls, x):
    return int(x)

def two(cls, y):
    return str(y)
```

Save this as bunch_method.py, and now we can construct our class as follows.

```
>>> import bunch_methods as bm
>>> Bunch_Class = type('Bunch_Class', (), bm.__dict__)
>>> bunch_object = Bunch_Class()
>>> bunch_object.__class__
<class '__main__.Bunch_Class'>
>>> bunch_object.one(1)
1
>>> bunch_object.two(1)
'1'
```

See the following post for a excellent (and long) guide on meta-classes.  [What is a metaclass in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple (but long) one-liner `lambda` that can do what you want (partially inspired by *Bakuriu*).

```
classify = lambda module: type(module.__name__, (), {key: staticmethod(value) if callable(value) else value for key, value in ((name, getattr(module, name)) for name in dir(module))})
```

You might find the following function easier to read and the loops easier to see in the comprehensions.

```
def classify(module):
    return type(module.__name__, (),
                {key: staticmethod(value) if callable(value) else value
                 for key, value in ((name, getattr(module, name))
                                    for name in dir(module))})
```

The usage is practically the same as *Bakuriu's* answer as you can see when talking to the interpreter.

```
>>> import math
>>> MathClass = classify(math)
>>> MathClass.sin(5)
-0.9589242746631385
>>> instance = MathClass()
>>> instance.sin(5)
-0.9589242746631385
>>> math.sin(5)
-0.9589242746631385
>>>
```

---

**Addendum:**

After realizing one of the uses of turning a module into a class, the following example program was written showing how to use the converted module as a base class. The pattern may not be recommendable for common use but does show an interesting application of the concept. The `classify` function should also be easier to read in the version shown below.

```
import math


def main():
    print(Point(1, 1) + Point.polar(45, Point.sqrt(2)))


def classify(module):
    return type(module.__name__, (), {
        key: staticmethod(value) if callable(value) else value
        for key, value in vars(module).items()
    })


class Point(classify(math)):

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.__x, self.__y = float(x), float(y)

    def __str__(self):
        return str((self.x, self.y))

    def __add__(self, other):
        return type(self)(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y)

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self.__x

    @property
    def y(self):
        return self.__y

    @classmethod
    def polar(cls, direction, length):
        radians = cls.radians(direction)
        x = round(cls.sin(radians) * length, 10)
        y = round(cls.cos(radians) * length, 10)
        return cls(x, y)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

No idea why you want to do this, but a simple approach could be:

```
def to_class(module):
    class TheClass(object): pass
    for attr in dir(module):
        val = getattr(module, attr)
        if callable(val):
            setattr(TheClass, attr, staticmethod(val))
    return TheClass
```

Usage:

```
>>> import math
>>> Math = to_class(math)
>>> m = Math()
>>> m.sin(5)
-0.9589242746631385
>>> math.sin(5)
-0.9589242746631385
>>> Math.sin(5)
-0.9589242746631385
```

If the module has also some variables, you could enhance it to add non-callable objects to the class too:

```
def to_class(module):
    class TheClass(object): pass
    for attr in dir(module):
        val = getattr(module, attr)
        if callable(val):
            setattr(TheClass, attr, staticmethod(val))
        else:
            setattr(TheClass, attr, val)
    return TheClass
```

However doing more than this becomes really hard and ugly and you must have a *really* good reason for doing this, otherwise it's wasted effort.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you would want this, as you can already use the module as a class, but anyway:

```
import bunch_methods as bm

print bm.one('1')
print bm.two(1)

class BunchClass:
    def __init__(self, methods):
        self.__dict__.update(methods.__dict__)

bc = BunchClass(bm)

print bc.one('2')
print bc.two(2)
```

Comment: This is wrong. The OP wants to transform a module into a new class. Your code transforms it into an *instance* of a class.

Comment: @Bakuriu That's true, but depending on the situation of the OP it is not necessarily a problem. In your answer you eventually make a instance too. If the OP doesn't need an instance, than why doesn't he just use the original module? But yes, you are correct.