# Encapsulate the scope of an imported module

Tags: python, class, namespaces, instance

Using the [hideous RoboClaw Python "library"](http://downloads.ionmc.com/code/roboclaw_python.zip) in a project, I can't seem to get past the fact that they threw a bunch of functions and global variables that deal with interfacing with physical hardware into a file.  Unfortunately, I am stuck using this library because when the vendor releases a new firmware for their board, they also update this file on their website; porting it to something useful would be a continuous effort.

The issue arises when I attempt to import it multiple times, once for each board that I have attached to USB.  Something (conceptually) like this would be ideal:

```
import roboclaw
class Board:
    def __init__(self):
        self.rc = roboclaw
```

Since the Python interpreter seems to maintain the same module reference in memory with every import, I can't seem to get it to create instances that exist in separate namespaces, essentially spitting out all kinds of I/O conflict errors when all boards incorrectly become assigned to the same `/dev/ttyACM` device file.  The closest that I seem to be able to get is [this answer provided by Noctis Skytower](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16719281/2962917), but it still isn't creating a separate namespaces for each `Board` instance.

Additionally, I have tried setting up dynamic imports using `imp` (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11285504/2962917)) and `importlib` (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16424060/2962917)) though both of these fail to import because they can't find the `roboclaw.py` file that sits in the same directory.

At a bit of a loss for the direction that I should be going on this, as I've never had to deal with this before.

Comment: oh god that is terrible! I figured out a way to override the global namespace so I'll post a possible solution in a moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok normally I would **condemn** hacks like the one I am suggesting but it seems you don't have much choice as the author of that package clearly did not understand the meaning of [object oriented programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming), there is a way to create a copy of a function with a different global scope by directly calling the `FunctionType()` contructor:

```
from types import FunctionType
from functools import wraps

def copy_func(func,global_namespace):
    "copies a function object with the new specified global scope"
    c = FunctionType(func.__code__,global_namespace,func.__name__,func.__defaults__,func.__closure__)
    try:
        c.__kwdefaults__ = func.__kwdefaults__
    except AttributeError:pass #this is only for python 3
    c = wraps(func)(c) #copy all metadata although there doesn't seem to be any for roboclaw
    return c
```

This way it does not affect the functions in the module at all but still uses your own namespace, you can then spoof a copy module with this:

```
class CopyScope:
    def __init__(self,module):
        own_scope = self.__dict__
        for name,thing in vars(module).items():
            if isinstance(thing,FunctionType):
                setattr(self, name, copy_func(thing, own_scope))
            else:
                setattr(self, name, thing)
                #you could also do own_scope[name] = .. instead of setattr() but I prefer setattr()
```

Although this only runs `copy_func` for all the module level function and not any methods that may use the global statement but I'd imagine that if the author understood what methods were you wouldn't need this at all.

I was able to test this with the following code:

```
import roboclaw
x = CopyScope(roboclaw)

x.crc_clear()
x.crc_update(4)

print(x._crc)
print(roboclaw._crc) #this will actually raise an error because it isn't defined in the original module yet.
```

EDIT: If you have not tried this it may be preferable to the above work around:

```
import sys
import roboclaw as robo1
del sys.modules["roboclaw"]
import roboclaw as robo2
assert robo1 is not robo2
```

Comment: Thank you! I believe that this is working--at least I have it working from IPython.  But, I am getting some errors from pyserial when I execute this application.  Once I can confirm that these are not related, I will mark this as solved.

Comment: oh s**o**me errors, not s**a**me errors. Ok I will stop changing the additions now.

Comment: looking back, making a copy of `vars(roboclaw)` then `reload(roboclaw)` might also work and feels less jank than deleting it from `sys.modules`. Still sticking with making a copy of the functions as primary solution since it seems most likely to be useful for someone doing something funky.